# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.support.ResourceEditorRegistrar

Tags: java, xml

This is my main method. I get an error in Application Context. I have added the XML file too.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {
        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/config/BeanLocations.xml");

        MailDao maildao = (MailDao)appContext.getBean("MailDao");

        MailBean mail = new MailBean();
        /** insert **/
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.println("Enter the from address\n");
        String fromAdd = sc.nextLine();
        mail.setFromAdd(fromAdd);

        System.out.println("Enter the To address\n");
        String toAddress = sc.nextLine();
        mail.setToAdd(toAddress);

        System.out.println("Enter the  Subject\n");
        String sub = sc.nextLine();
        mail.setSubject(sub);

        System.out.println("Enter the  Message\n");
        String msg = sc.nextLine();
        mail.setMessage(msg);

        mail.setAttachements(null);

        /*for getting current time */
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        java.util.Date now = calendar.getTime();
        java.sql.Timestamp msgdate = new java.sql.Timestamp(now.getTime());
        mail.setDate(msgdate);

        mail.setSnt_status(false);

        maildao.save(mail);
    }
}
```

**BeanLocations.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
    <!-- Database Configuration -->
    <import resource="../database/DataSource.xml"/>
    <import resource="../database/Hibernate.xml"/>

    <!-- Beans Declaration -->
    <import resource="../beans/Mail.xml"/>
</beans>
```

**DataSource.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>properties/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Hibernate.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>     

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>-->

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>/hibernate/Mail.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

If I uncomment the line `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` I get the following error:

> cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'property' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

**Now I'm getting this error.**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.support.ResourceEditorRegistrar.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;)V
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:355)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.RML.Main.Main.main(Main.java:43)
```

In this line

> `ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/config/BeanLocations.xml");`

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>RMLApplication</groupId>
  <artifactId>RMLApplication</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>RMLApplication</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>



  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

   <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Java.Net</id>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


  <!-- Java Mail API -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derbyclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>10.12.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring AOP dependency -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate framework -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Quartz API -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opensymphony.quartz/quartz -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensymphony.quartz</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz-jobs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.studio/org.apache.commons.logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>


        <!-- log4j -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**I'm getting this error**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/database/Hibernate.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.RML.Main.Main.main(Main.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.supports(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.getBeanInfo(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:46)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:270)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:173)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:63)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyHandler(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:725)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.isWritableProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 27 more
```

**Mail.hbm.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">


   <!-- Stock Data Access Object -->
   <bean id="MailDao" class="com.RML.Dao.Impl.MailDaoImpl" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
   </bean>


</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the property as

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

inside props tag of property in Hibernate.xml file.

It will look like this:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

Comment: Looks like you have some missing jars.

Comment: I'm using Maven . so all jars are automatically downloaded . right?? i'll update the pom.xml file

Comment: You need to add this dependency in pom.xml

Comment: <dependency><groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Thanks much. but Still there's error which I can rectify.

Comment: Updated the question can you follow up?

Comment: You have defined the dao bean in mail.hbm.xml file, but i can see you are referring that file as mapping file in Hibernate.xml file. Mapping files should contain the class mappings, not the bean definitions. Moreover, you can combine all the xml's into one single xml file.

Comment: For the exception that you are getting, I can see you are using hibernate 5, but you have defined org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean in your sessionfactory. Use org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean for hibernate 5.

Comment: **_Thanks Much @Abhay Jain_**